# Matlab : How to compare num with num of excel without compare character in excel>it make my code error

Tags: excel, matlab, compare, comparison, ocr

example:
I have a number 123456 from excel.

and i have a text from ocr is '123456'. I change to num with str2num is 123456

already I can compare num with num if flie excel don't have character.

but if file excel have character in row or column . it say error

how to fix this if i want to compare only number .i don't want to compare

character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str2num` returns empty mattrix if it cant convert string to number. So you can just check for this:

```
r = str2num('55');

if ~isempty(r)
    disp('r is number')
else
    disp('r is empty')
end
```